# Question about proof for bipartite containing no odd cycles

Tags: proof-explanation, bipartite-graphs

I red the proof from here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Graph_is_Bipartite_iff_No_Odd_Cycles

> **Sufficient Condition**
>
> Let $G=(V,E)$ be bipartite.
>
> So, let $V=A∪B$ such that $A∩B=∅$ and that all edges $e∈E$ are such that $e$
>   is of the form $\{a,b\}$ where $a∈A$ and $b∈B$.
>
> (This is the definition of a bipartite graph.)
>
> Suppose $G$ has (at least) one odd cycle $C$.
>
> Let the length of $C$ be $n$.
>
> Let $C=(v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n,v_1)$.
>
> WLOG, let $v_1∈A$. It follows that $v_2∈B$ and hence $v_3∈A$, and so on.
>
> Hence we see that $∀k∈\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, we have:
>
> ```
> $v_k∈\{A:B:k$ odd $k$ even
> ```
>
> But as $n$ is odd, $v_n∈A$.
>
> But $v_1∈A$, and $v_nv_1∈C_n$.
>
> So $v_nv_1∈E$ which contradicts the assumption that $G$ is bipartite.
>
> Hence if $G$ is bipartite, it has no odd cycles.

I don't understand how  "So $v_nv_1∈E$ which contradicts the assumption that G is bipartite." is it because both $v_n$ and $v_1$ are in the set $A$ so that's a contradiction of $A$ and $B$ being disjoint?

Comment: Draw a random bipartite graph and just try to find cycles of length 3 or 5. Trying to find an odd cycle   will make you understand why you will never find one and what the  logic of this proof is

Answer (score 0):

No. We have an edge $\{v_n, v_1\} \in E$ where $v_n, v_1 \in A$. This contradicts the fact that $G$ is bipartite, and so each edge should have been of the form $\{a, b\}$ with $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. The indicated edge does not have this form, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why do you say "No"? You give the same explanation I meant.

Comment: @Celeritas: He just misinterpreted you a bit, but you've both saying the same thing. We often think of a bipartite graph as a graph with vertices from $A,B$ such that there is no edge between any two vertices in $A$, nor between any two vertices in $B$. This is equivalent to what you said, though it feels a bit different.